# Configure Ansible to write logs to a different file on managed servers

Tags: rhel, logs, ansible

I would like to know if there is a way to configure `Ansible` to have its own log files instead of writing to `/var/log/messages` on RHEL server.

Answer (score 1):

According to their site:

http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#log-path

```
This behavior is not on by default. Note that ansible will, without 
this setting, record module arguments called to the syslog of managed machines.
```

Comment: I have that setting on my local Ansible server, are you saying that I need to have `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` on each managed server to be able to do this ? I did a quick test and it did not work.